# WPF VB.NET RectangleGeometry Rect Structure Multibinding

Tags: wpf, multibinding, rect

I have the following XAML which works perfectly (along with the myRectConverter class). The only problem is I need this to be converted into VB.NET code so it can be produced in the application dynamically.

```
  <Canvas Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Height="{Binding ElementName=FeatureOverlay1, Path=ActualHeight}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="Canvas1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="{Binding ElementName=FeatureOverlay1, Path=ActualWidth}" Background="Red">
    <Canvas.Clip>
      <RectangleGeometry x:Name="clipRect" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5">
        <RectangleGeometry.Rect>
          <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myRectConverter}">
            <Binding ElementName="Canvas1" Path="Width"/>
            <Binding ElementName="Canvas1" Path="Height"/>
          </MultiBinding>
        </RectangleGeometry.Rect>
      </RectangleGeometry>
    </Canvas.Clip>
    <Image Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Name="TestImage" Stretch="Fill" Source="/FluidSize;component/Images/Desert.jpg" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
  </Canvas>
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
Dim rectGeometry As RectangleGeometry = New RectangleGeometry

rectGeometry.RadiusX = 5
rectGeometry.RadiusY = 5

Dim multiBinding As MultiBinding = New MultiBinding()
multiBinding.Converter = New RectConverter

Dim binding As Binding = New Binding()
binding.ElementName = "Canvas1"
binding.Path = New PropertyPath("Width")
multiBinding.Bindings.Add(binding)

binding = New Binding()
binding.ElementName = "Canvas1"
binding.Path = New PropertyPath("Height")
multiBinding.Bindings.Add(binding)

' Need to somehow add the multibinding object to the rectGeometry as a Rect structure, then assign to Canvas1.Clip
```

Does anyone know how to get this working?

Thanks

Ben

Answer (score 1):

```
BindingOperations.SetBinding(rectGeometry, RectangleGeometry.RectProperty, multiBinding);
```

Alternatively:

```
rectGeometry.SetBinding(RectangleGeometry.RectProperty, multiBinding);
```

Comment: Hi Kent. Thanks for the suggestion, however they don't seem to be achieving the expected result. rectGeometry doesn't have SetBinding available so I used the BindingOperations option. When the RectConverter class is called, I get the following error: "Conversion from type 'NamedObject' to type 'Double' is not valid". If I browse the objects in the debugger, I can see the Rect structure is empty and the Canvas1 Width/Height properties are bound to the root of the RectangularGeometry object, not the Rect structure.